# Stateful Recurrent Neural Networks with fit_generator()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

***Context***

I read some blogs about the implementation of stateful recurrent neural networks in Keras (for example [here](https://fairyonice.github.io/Stateful-LSTM-model-training-in-Keras.html) and [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stateful-stateless-lstm-time-series-forecasting-python/)).
There are also several questions regarding stateful RNNs on stackoverflow, whereby [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382859/keras-stateful-lstm-fit-generator-how-to-use-batch-size-1) comes close to mine.

The linked tutorials use the `fit()`-method instead of `fit_generator()` and pass states by manually iterating over the epochs with `epochs=1` in `fit()` like in this example taken from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stateful-stateless-lstm-time-series-forecasting-python/):

```py
# fit an LSTM network to training data
def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons):
    X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
        model.reset_states()
    return model
```

***My question***

I'd like to use `fit_generator()` instead of `fit()`, but also use stateless LSTM/GRU-layers.
What I was missing in other stackoverflow-questions like the one linked above is:

1. *Can I proceed in the same way as with `fit()`, meaning setting `epochs=1`, and iterate over it for x times while setting
   `model.reset_states()` in each iteration like in the example?*
2. *Or does `fit_generator()` already reset states only after finishing `batch_size` when `stateful=True` is used (what would be great)?*
3. *Or does `fit_generator()` reset states after each single batch (what would be a problem)?*

The latter question deals in particular with this statement form [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stateful-stateless-lstm-time-series-forecasting-python/):

> *Stateless*: In the stateless LSTM configuration, internal state is
>   reset after each training batch or each batch when making predictions.
>   *Stateful*: In the stateful LSTM configuration, internal state is only
>   reset when the reset_state() function is called.